# Knockout: highlight element on observable updating

Tags: knockout.js

I want to highlight an element bound to an observable when the observable is updated but not when the binding of the observable is inited.

I tried using a custom binding:

```
<div data-bind="updateHighlighting: name, text: name"></div>
<input data-bind="value: name" />

ko.bindingHandlers.updateHighlighting = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).effect("highlight", 2000);
    }
};

var vm = {
    name: ko.observable("Diego")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

But the update callback runs not only when the observable is updated but also at the init of the custom binding. So there is an undesired element highlighting at the init of the binding.

Can i know, inside the update callback, if i'm at the init of the binding in order to do something like the following?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.updateHighlighting = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if(!isInit)
            $(element).effect("highlight", 2000);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be to use Knockouts `ko.utils.domData` functions like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.updateHighlighting = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var key = "_my_init_key_",
            isInit = ko.utils.domData.get(element, key);

        if(isInit) {
            $(element).effect("highlight", 2000);
        }
        else {
            ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
        }
    }
};
```

This is really just setting an expando property on the element, so using it to keep the state.  Knockout does clean it up when it removes the element, if you use the API, although when storing a primitive it is not a big deal.

Since, you are using jQuery, you could also use $.data to store a flag as well.

Comment: Only I had to add "ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());" at the beginning of the update callback to get it to work.

Comment: @DiegoPlutino - yes, you would want to grab a dependency to whatever you want to trigger the update by unwrapping the observable.